# PHP+MySql join and like from table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want search in `table` and relationship

> Table 1

```
id  title
---------------------
1   kia
2   chevrolet
3   benz
4   bmw
```

> Table 2

```
id  brand
---------------------
1   1
2   3
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   4
7   1
8   3
```

> Result

```
2,8
```

If i search `benz` , i want show result from `table 2` but like from `table 1`

My code

```
SELECT * FROM `table2` LEFT JOIN `table1` ON table2.brand=table1.id WHERE table1.title LIKE '%benz%'
```

But this code not return result

Comment: Can help me ? thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE title LIKE '%benz%');
```

Let me know if that worked for you.